# Override a keyword argument in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyword-argument

Python version: 3.10.0

I have multiple functions using same arguments, mostly with same values also, so I decided to use keyword arguments instead to reduce the amount of parameters provided to the functions.

However, now I ran into this issue: What if I would like to override some of the keyword arguments with custom values, without altering the 'global defaults'?

Using a simplified example:

```
def func(arg1, arg2, **kwargs):
    print(f"Received: {arg1} {arg2} {kwargs}")
    print(f"Special: {kwargs.get('special')}")


def func2(arg1, arg2, **kwargs):
    print(f"Received: {arg1} {arg2} {kwargs}")
    print(f"Special: {kwargs.get('special')}")


common = {
    'param1': 10,
    'param2': True,
    'special': "SPECIAL_DEFAULT"
}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    func("test", "some-value", **common)
    func2(99, None, **common)

    # For example, for this call, I want to override one of the common arguments with a different value
    # Without altering var common that is used globally
    # However, it throws TypeError because 'special' is defined in multiple places now
    func("test", "some-another-value", special="SOMETHING_ELSE", **common)
```

I have stored all common keyword arguments in a dict that is provided into all functions using the common arguments.

However, when I try to override some of the keyword arguments Im getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  line 24, in <module>
    func("test", "some-another-value", special="SOMETHING_ELSE", **common)
TypeError: __main__.func() got multiple values for keyword argument 'special'
```

Meaning that Python cant decide which of the provided values it would use.

What would be the cleanest (most elegant) way to overcome this issue?

Comment: A nice solution was given here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51363208/how-to-deal-with-multiple-keyword-arguments

Comment: @JanJaapMeijerink yep, that's a duplicate. Please vote to close next time.

Comment: I personally like the way this question was framed much more than the way the question I linked was framed.

Comment: I searched for this quite a long time and could not find the exact problem & solution, so I decided to post a new question. Thank you for pointing that one out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> foo = {'bar': 'baz'}
>>> {**foo, 'bar': 42}
{'bar': 42}
>>> {'bar': 42, **foo}
{'bar': 'baz'}
```

So:

```
func("test", "some-another-value", **{**common, "special": "SOMETHING_ELSE"})
```

Answer (score 3):

> What would be the cleanest (most elegant) way to overcome this issue?

I would use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) (from `functools` module in standard library) in this case consider following simple example

```
import functools
def volume(**kwargs):
    return kwargs["x"]*kwargs["y"]*kwargs["z"]
volume = functools.partial(volume, x=1, y=1, z=1)
print(volume())  # 1
print(volume(z=5))  # 5
print(volume(x=2,y=3,z=4))  # 24
```

`functools.partial` provide partial object, which behave like function provided to it with set default values.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new dictionary with the updated values:

```
def func(arg1, arg2, **kwargs):
    print(f"Received: {arg1} {arg2} {kwargs}")
    print(f"Special: {kwargs.get('special')}")


def func2(arg1, arg2, **kwargs):
    print(f"Received: {arg1} {arg2} {kwargs}")
    print(f"Special: {kwargs.get('special')}")


common = {
    'param1': 10,
    'param2': True,
    'special': "SPECIAL_DEFAULT"
}

if __name__ == '__main__':
  func("test", "some-value", **common)
  func2(99, None, **common)
  spcl = dict(common)
  spcl['special'] = "SOMETHING_ELSE"
  func("test", "some-another-value",  **spcl)
  
  print(common)
  print(spcl)
```

Outputs:

```
Received: test some-value {'param1': 10, 'param2': True, 'special': 'SPECIAL_DEFAULT'}
Special: SPECIAL_DEFAULT
Received: 99 None {'param1': 10, 'param2': True, 'special': 'SPECIAL_DEFAULT'}
Special: SPECIAL_DEFAULT
Received: test some-another-value {'param1': 10, 'param2': True, 'special': 'SOMETHING_ELSE'}
Special: SOMETHING_ELSE
{'param1': 10, 'param2': True, 'special': 'SPECIAL_DEFAULT'}
{'param1': 10, 'param2': True, 'special': 'SOMETHING_ELSE'}
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
def func(arg1, arg2, **kwargs):
    print(f"Received: {arg1} {arg2} {kwargs}")
    print(f"Special: {kwargs.get('special')}")


common = {"param1": 10, "param2": True, "special": "SPECIAL_DEFAULT"}
special_params = {**common, "special": "SOMETHING_ELSE"}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    func("test", "some-value", **common)
    func(99, None, **common)
    func("test", "some-another-value", **special_params)
```

Comment: This solution has a problem that the original parameters from common (the parameters that were not overridden (from the dict 'common') and wanted to be preserved as-is, are not inserted into the last function call.

Comment: Ohhhh yeah actually I see what you mean.